# linux Text parsing - "select column and remove integer using delimiter"

Tags: awk, sed, text-parsing

I am trying to remove integer by selecting delimiter.

I want to select a 3rd and 4th column and remove the port after ":" delimeter, i have tried the command the below. But it removes the first match on time **00:56:37**

```
sed 's/:/ /'
```

output now,

```
2016-03-29 00:56:37 0.0.0.0:48130 10.0.1.117:80 404 404 http://52.4.12.23:80/CHANGELOG.txt "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
2016-03-29 00:57:20 1.1.1.1:37020 10.0.0.197:80 404 404 http://52.4.12.23:80/readme.html "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
2016-03-29 02:52:46 2.2.2.2:47442 10.0.0.197:80 404 404 http://testp3.pospr.waw.pl:80/testproxy.php "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
```

output needed

```
2016-03-29 00:56:37 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.117 404 404 http://52.4.12.23:80/CHANGELOG.txt "Mozilla/5.0
2016-03-29 00:57:20 1.1.1.1 10.0.0.197 404 404 http://52.4.12.23:80/readme.html "Mozilla/5.0
2016-03-29 02:52:46 2.2.2.2 10.0.0.197 404 404 http://testp3.pospr.waw.pl:80/testproxy.php "Mozilla/5.0
```

Want to remove port no from ip **2.2.2.2:48130** to **2.2.2.2** but should not affect other columns

Please share your thoughts...

***Thanks Tom and Lars both worked***

Comment: Your input and output don't match up. Have you tried anything yourself? Please [edit] your question to address these two issues.

Comment: you also removed the `:` from the http: and before 80. Intentional or typo?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: @karakfa - sorry its typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use sed to match the IP address and remove the port:

```
sed -E 's/(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+):[0-9]+/\1/' file
```

The IP address is matched and used in the replacement, discarding the port.

This pattern will match the first thing on each line that looks vaguely like an IP address (i.e. four integers separated by dots), which isn't a problem for the input you've shown but is something to bear in mind.

If you want to make two substitutions on each line, then you can do that too:

```
sed -E 's/(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+):[0-9]+/\1/;s/(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+):[0-9]+/\1/' file
```

If you use awk, then you can target the third field directly but you will also reformat any lines that you touch.

Comment: Thanks Tom that worked...  If you dont mind please share any good link to study sed...

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk and its sub function on the third and fourth field, like this:

```
awk '{ sub(/:[0-9]+/, "", $3 );sub(/:[0-9]+/, "", $4 ) ; print  }' file
```

This will strip the port number from all lines.

Comment: HI Lars,  Thanks it worked... If you dont mind please share any good link to study awk.

Comment: @Sasee, call me old fashioned but I liked Gawk: Effective AWK Programming, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/